# Join multiple tables with Having expression

Tags: mysql, sql

There are 2 tables Contacts & BlockedEntries

Table: Contact

```
Id 
FirstName 
LastName 
Email 
JobTitle
```

Table: BlockedEntries

```
Id 
Email
```

Trying to find the entries from contact table with more than one occurence of blockedEntries

```
SELECT email, COUNT(*)  as cc, GROUP_CONCAT( id  SEPARATOR '#') AS ContactIds 
FROM contacts 
where email IN (SELECT email FROM BlockedEntries)
GROUP BY email   
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Is there any way to get some more additional details like first name ,last Name, email,job title  etc for the entries with count is more than 1

Unfortunately there is no relation between these 2 tables and email is the only possible mapping . There can be 1 or more entries present in COntact table with same email address

Sample data

```
Id  FirstName LastName Email JobTitle

12  sam   j  samj@gmail.com  engineer
23  bos   j  bosj@gmail.com  accountnt
34  cas   j  samj@gmail.com  engineer
33  xxx   j  bosj@gmail.com  fied
55  dfe   c  dfe@gmail.com   student


Table: BlockedEntries

Id  Email              CreateDate
1    samj@gmail.com     09/12/2020 19:30:20
2    bosj@gmail.com     09/12/2020 19:30:20
3    dfe@gmail.com       09/12/2020 19:30:20


Result expecting 

email              id  firstname lastName jobtitle 

samj@gmail.com    12  sam   j     engineer
samj@gmail.com    34  bos   j     accountnt
bosj@gmail.com    23  cas   j      engineer
bosj@gmail.com    33  xxx   j      fied


dfe@gmail.com only 1 instance and no need to add this to result set
```

Comment: Please add sample data.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no relation between these 2 tables and email ?? YES there is it's on email the fact that there is no fk is not a problem, the fact that it's not indexed may impact performance though

Comment: This is just a one time reporting from 2 tables across different databases So perfomace is not really a concern I managed to get the ID of duplicate emails But it is nice to have some more info. I can use same GROUP_CONCAT against other columns but want to make it in differnt rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On MySQL 8+, I would use `COUNT()` as an analytic function here:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY email) email_cnt
    FROM contacts
)

SELECT c.Id, c.FirstName, c.LastName, c.Email, c.JobTitle
FROM cte c
WHERE email_cnt > 1 AND
      EXISTS (
          SELECT 1
          FROM BlockedEntries be
          WHERE be.email = c.email
      );
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your data example you just need two inner joins, one with the BlockedEntries which will get you all the related emails between BlockedEntries  and Contact table and another join with a subquery which will get the emails more than once on Contact  table.

Try:

```
select c.Id,
       c.FirstName,
       c.LastName,
       c.Email,
       c.JobTitle
from Contact c
inner join BlockedEntries be on be.Email=c.Email  
inner join (select Email
            from Contact
            group by Email
            having count(*)>1 
          ) as cnt on cnt.Email=c.Email;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/P9Y4RHfu